# PayPal Live Transaction Completed but IPN does not update from Pending

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We're using PayPal Payments Standard and IPN to process payment transactions and enable digital goods download after our IPN listener script recieves notification of a completed transaction.

We've done thorough testing on the PayPal sandbox and made sure our scripts handle different scenarios properly.

Just to be sure, before opening the sales to public, we've done some testing with the PayPal live interface - performed a few small sales using a previously verified PayPal account to pay for the goods.

Our IPN listener script has immediately received notifications, but the `payment_status` in both of them was '`pending`' with `pending_reason` = '`paymentreview`'. After logging to our seller PayPal account a few minutes after making the payment, both transactions have the status '`Completed`' and are ready to ship, yet our IPN listener did not receive any further notification updating the status of the transactions.

By checking the IPN history on our seller PayPal account, we can see that only the initial messages for both payments have been sent (with status '`Pending`').

The PayPal developer docs are explicit about not allowing the download or shipping goods before the transaction is succesfully completed, yet we do not receive an update via IPN even 48+ hours after the payments.

We did not experience any such problem during testing period on PayPal sandbox interface.

Is this an issue with the IPN interface, or there is something that can be configured through our PayPal account that will resolve this issue and make IPN behaviour consistant with PayPal developer docs?

Comment: If you're sure you're not actually getting the update then it must be an issue with IPN.  I'd recommend that you [contact PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your advice. We are positive about IPN not delivering updates about transaction status change because IPN history on our seller account shows only the initial messages have been sent with transaction status marked as 'Pending'. We've already reported the issue yesterday with PayPal MTS but have received no response from them yet. Hopefully this will be resolved soon because it breaks our sales functionality.

Comment: One thing I just thought of.  Do you have IPN configured in your PayPal account profile or did you do it using notify_url in the PayPal request?

Comment: Actually it is both configured in our PayPal account profile but is also sent via notify_url parameter (they both point to same url). Do you think this could be the reason for the issue, because the developer docs allow for different IPN urls in notify_url? I guess I coud try removing one of the two and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Well just tried removing the `notify_url` variable completely, leaving only the IPN setting on PayPal account profile, made another payment, but the IPN behavior is the same. Only the initial IPN message is sent marking the payment as `Pending`, yet the transaction is `Completed` in payment history on PayPal account profile a minute after the payment has been made. IPN history shows no further messages have been sent.

Comment: I was thinking if you were using notify_url only that may be the reason, but if you've definitely got it setup in the profile then that should be triggering the follow ups when the status changes.

Comment: We did try both combinations (using only profile setup / notify_url) but there is no difference in the behaviour in all cases. We had finally been contacted from the PayPal MTS and they think it might be a bug on their side, so hopefully the issue will be resolved in a reasonable time because it is currently blocking the start of our sales. Thanks again.